# groovy with regular expression

Tags: regex, groovy, soapui

I try to learn groovy in SoapUI and now I have a problem with a regular expression in groovy.

I try build a regular expression in groovy to parse this text:

> [EM6111949VA61=cfefcgjnjcidaiieodmlgfijaiknankpiodhghbagndikijiieicfhiiiojmfcfgjjkokkoilinbkkedcaafplikgjhomkhnopjhfhpjgkadalbkeenengiapjpeaiemokenfckjbeho;
>   path=/bla/bla; secure; HttpOnly]

The result must be:

> EM6111949VA61=cfefcgjnjcidaiieodmlgfijaiknankpiodhghbagndikijiieicfhiiiojmfcfgjjkokkoilinbkkedcaafplikgjhomkhnopjhfhpjgkadalbkeenengiapjpeaiemokenfckjbeho

My groovy source-code in SoapUI  is:

```
erg='[EM6111949VA61=cfefcgjnjcidaiieodmlgfijaiknankpiodhghbagndikijiieicfhiiiojmfcfgjjkokkoilinbkkedcaafplikgjhomkhnopjhfhpjgkadalbkeenengiapjpeaiemokenfckjbeho; path=/bla/bla; secure; HttpOnly]'


def muster = /(?<=\[)[\w]+=[\w]+/

(erg ==~ muster).each {
log.info "Muster $it"
}
```

the log.info result is: Muster false

I try the text with the Expression::

```
(?<=\[)[\w]+=[\w]+ to http://www.regexe.de/
```

And the result is what I need,

> EM6111949VA61=cfefcgjnjcidaiieodmlgfijaiknankpiodhghbagndikijiieicfhiiiojmfcfgjjkokkoilinbkkedcaafplikgjhomkhnopjhfhpjgkadalbkeenengiapjpeaiemokenfckjbeho

What is the correct Syntax in groovy

Thanks a lot for your answers

Michael

Comment: Would you mind showing the response, data that you are trying to extract and what are you trying to achieve in soapUI? what assertion are you doing - `Script Assertion`?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern works, but the `==~` operator requires the whole string to match this pattern. Your current regex is equal to `/^(?<=\[)[\w]+=[\w]+\z/`.

Use `=~` that allows *partial* matches, not `==~` (that requires full string matches).

Note you may write `[\w]` as `\w` since `\w` is the only "atom" in the character class.

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/JCxxlc):

```
def erg='[EM6111949VA61=cfefcgjnjcidaiieodmlgfijaiknankpiodhghbagndikijiieicfhiiiojmfcfgjjkokkoilinbkkedcaafplikgjhomkhnopjhfhpjgkadalbkeenengiapjpeaiemokenfckjbeho; path=/bla/bla; secure; HttpOnly]'
def regex = /(?<=\[)\w+=\w+/
def muster = erg =~ regex
(0..<muster.count).each { print muster[it] }
```

Output:

```
EM6111949VA61=cfefcgjnjcidaiieodmlgfijaiknankpiodhghbagndikijiieicfhiiiojmfcfgjjkokkoilinbkkedcaafplikgjhomkhnopjhfhpjgkadalbkeenengiapjpeaiemokenfckjbeho
```